# Remove ugly fat bazel from gnome-terminal with multiple-tabs

Tags: gnome-terminal, gui

When I start `gnome-terminal` it looks quite pleasant but when I open another tab it's borders turns ugly:

[image: fat-ugly-gnome-terminal-bezel]

**How can I preserve thin bezel while using multiple tabs?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After some messing around, I figured it out.

Edit `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-terminal.css` and add:

```
 TerminalWindow .notebook {
   padding: 0;
   border-width: 0;
 }
```

Bug found on this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/+bug/694468

Comment: Hmm, it seems to make the bezel quite small for me in both gnome-terminal and gnome-terminator. Thanks for pointing this out! I find it kind of hilarious that even Mark Shuttleworth can post a bug to launchpad and have it not fixed 2 years later ;)

Comment: Messed around with it some more and finally got it to work!  Now to see if I can apply this fix to Terminator as well....

Comment: @Ibrahim they had GTK2 2 years ago, now is way easier with CSS.

Comment: Heh true, but Mark Shuttleworth replied a year ago asking if that fix could be incorporated into Ubuntu, and it wasn't ;)

Comment: As suggested in a comment [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/773908/370623), you can use `find / -name gnome-terminal.css` to find the most up-to-date version.  I had to edit `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.20/apps/gnome-terminal.css`, not `gtk-3.0`.

Answer (score 18):

Well its a good practice in general not to modify the original files but override their values according to your preferences.

If you don't already have it, create or open a gtk.css file in this path

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css
```

Paste the following code, close all terminals and start one new.

```
@define-color bg-grey #222;
@define-color active-grey #333;
@define-color border-grey #555;


TerminalWindow .notebook {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #eee;
  background-color: shade(@active-grey, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
  border: 1px solid @border-grey;
  background-color: shade(@active-grey, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
  background-color: shade(@bg-grey, 1);
}
```

Now, not only it will remove the borders as you intended but will also "fit" better with the dark background, my eyes "hurt" with the light gray. The result when you have multiple tabs it should look like this, which of course you can customize it by tampering the color variables according to your preferences.

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm +1

Answer (score 9):

Mine based on @topless and @jibreel answers.
Transparent background and a dark theme. Awesome.

```
@define-color bg-grey #222;
@define-color active #313131;

TerminalWindow .notebook {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: shade(@active, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
    background-color: shade(@active,1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: shade(@bg-grey, 1);
}
```

[image]

Comment: All of these answers were helpful and taught me how awesome GTK is for having themes based on CSS. This answer, though... this one is the best. Great look. I won't even be tweaking this any further as I planned.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @topless, 
also edited it further to look like this,
note the border-radius: 0, to avoid white space

```
@define-color bg-grey #222;
@define-color active #300A24;

TerminalWindow .notebook {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #eee;
  background-color: shade(@active-grey, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
  background-color: shade(@active, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: shade(@bg-grey, 1);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can either try another theme, configure Ambiance to your likings, or get one of these ( from Ubuntu software center):

- Terminator
- xterm
- Roxterm
- Tilda
- Guake
- ...

Comment: I do know that there are other terminal apps available, they all look ugly to me