# Where I can find a list of all css classes that composes the terminal?

Tags: themes, gnome-terminal

I've just found on Google a way to write my own `css` to put some styles on the terminal. At the beginning I was looking to add something to know which tab was active.

Now I'm curious about know more about what I can change on the terminal using `css` but I didn't find a lot of information and neither a lot of classes or elements that are available.

Does anyone know where I can find more information about it? I'm only interested in the styles of the terminal.

By the way, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with

Comment: when you use a theme you can find the css file there: 
/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/apps/gnome-terminal.css 
for example. could try to 'find / -name gnome-terminal.css'

Answer (score 1):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1479239

Looks like there's a full post on customizing various classes. Unfortunately, aside from looking at the source code and going through it, it doesn't look like very many people have created a list for the specific classes that can be used in the CSS file.

With a bit of looking around, at least for the issue that you mentioned, this is what I found. Seems to get done what you're wanting.

http://harts.net/reece/2013/02/26/highlighting-the-active-tab-in-gnome-terminal/

Instructions provided in link:

Create (or edit) ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css.

```
Add these lines:

@define-color ubuntu_orange #fb9267;

TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
 background-color: shade(@ubuntu_orange,1.1);
}
```

Might I suggest that you do a lot of testing in a Virtual Machine before doing this. Would hate to have a broken terminal!

Comment: The way to change the active tab I found it because I started looking for it. My curiosity came after discover I can change more parts of the terminal but what I can find is for the background and font